# I can't hanbleChange with react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to change it by using contact-select, but I keep getting an error.
When I select this option, I can see this error. help me plz.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1VgR.png)

this is options

```
const options = [
 { value: 'descript', label: '주관식' },
 { value: 'choice', label: '객관식' },
 { value: 'combine', label: '다중식' }
];
```

and this is onChange fuction

```
onChangeTmpType = (e) => {
 this.setState({
   tmp_type: e.target.value
 })
}
```

this is React-Select

```
<Select
  components={makeAnimated()}
  value={this.state.tmp_type}
  onChange={this.onChangeTmpType}
  options={options}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your onChangeTmpType function as follows.

```
onChangeTmpType = (e) => {
 this.setState({
   tmp_type: e.value
 })
}
```

The reason for this as (@Laura mentioned before) is that the e from react select only contains the value and the label .

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [documentation here](https://react-select.com/props), the `onChange` function looks like this:

```
function (
  One of <
  Object,
  Array<Object>,
  null,
  undefined
>,
  {
    action required One of <
      "select-option",
      "deselect-option",
      "remove-value",
      "pop-value",
      "set-value",
      "clear",
      "create-option"
    >
    }
  ) => undefined
```

and the `e` const you declare actually has the following structure:

```
{
  label: ...,
  value: ...
}
```

so no `target` key here but directly `e.value` if what you want is to access the props `value`.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/n33qwrv96m) with `console.log` so you can see what's happening.